# Jquery select src from source dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html div like below code

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<?php for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) { ?>
<div class="swiper-slide" id=<?php echo $i; ?>>
        <img src="videos/Capture.PNG" alt="">
        <source class="a" src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Now I want if I click on `swiper-slide` class then I need source src attribute.

I have tried below code

```
<script>
   $('.swiper-slide').click(function(){
      var value = $('.swiper-slider > source').attr('src'); 
   }
</script>
```

In this time it's working only for 1st image.How can I make it dynamic ?

Comment: `$(this).find('source').attr('src')` use this

Comment: `$(this).find('source').attr('src');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are two mistakes in your code:

1. `attar()` should be `attr()`
2. Missing `)` of the event handler.

You can use `find()` with `$(this)`. `$(this)` inside the event handler is the element reference on which the event has occurred.

```
$(this)              // Element that is clicked
    .find('source')  // Get `<source>` element inside clicked element
    .attr('src');    // Get `src` attribute value
```

When `$('.swiper-slide')` is used, it'll select all the elements in the DOM having the `swiper-slide` class and when `attr()` method is used on it, the value of the passed attribute for the first element from the matched set is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use clicked element context `this` in click event along with `.find()`:

```
$('.swiper-slide').click(function(){
  var value = $('source',this).attr('src'); //or $(this).find('source').attr('src'); 
});
```

Comment: check again :) made same mistake :)